# Django: How to obtain data from html? How can the value of int increase over time? How do I stop a button from working when the value reaches 100?

Tags: javascript, html, django, sqlite, game-development

im working on a project of a web game with Django. The main idea is that the player has a continuous increasing infection meter. He would need to scan mutiple qr code (representing a location, like the game city hunt), to decrease his infection. If it reaches 100, he would become a zombie and a button will be blocked or hide.

-To acheive this, I'm having some ideas but i don't know know exactly how i should implement it. Here are the challenges:

1.How to get data from html to my database?(I uses SQLite)
-I want to recieve data from the html (the qrcode will turn into points (a -ve value) and i need to add that to the player To decrease his infection rate)

2.How to make a value of int increases overtime?

- I want to add an **dynamic**infection attribute to the player,so that it increase through time(like the Enlightenment meter in Don't starve if you know what i mean lol ) . Should i mainly be coding the timer and the value in html and java script or I should code in python (django)instead? Where should i build the timer thing?

3.How to stop a button from working when that value matches 100?
-When the value reaches 100, it should hide or block a button in another html page,( which is made by my friend so i don't know the details).

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try to isolate each question that gives you problems separately. Also explain a bit better how your game works by including the code. Are your issues on the frontend or backend? Is your game coded in JS or python?